# Django automatic remove user if is no verified in time

Tags: python, django

I have a flag in django is_verified and i override User to CreateUser
now i want automatic remove from db user if flag > 10 min == False, but when True nothing do.
I created something like this in class CreateUser but this didn't work.

```
def remove_user_time(self):
    user = super().objects.get(email=self.email)
    register_time = user.date_joined
    ten_minutes_later = (register_time + timedelta(hours=0.16))
    if ten_minutes_later == datetime.now():
        if user.is_verified == False:
            user.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def remove_user_time(self):
    user = super().objects.get(email=self.email)
    register_time = user.date_joined
    ten_minutes_later = (register_time + timedelta(hours=0.16))
    if ten_minutes_later > datetime.now():
        if user.is_verified == False:
            user.delete()
```

use greater than `>`, instead of `==`

equal will only be true if you check at the exact time

Comment: Thanks its work for me with "if ten_minutes_later < timezone.now():" .